# what is this in C++?

Tags: c++, variables

```
int* i;

int * i;

int **i;
```

i know

```
int *i;
```

represent pointer variable

Comment: this is really fun. are there any difference between int*i, int *i, int *i ? huh. If you really dont know about pointer, I can give real life example "matryoshka". int i encapsulated by int *i ... int **i ... int ***i ( ... = encapsulated by ). int ***i hold adress of int **i ... int *i ... int i (hold adress of ).

Answer (score 5):

Spacing doesn't make any difference, so the first two are identical.

```
int** i;
```

Is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

For example, if `i` held a pointer value, then that would mean that in the memory starting at that address there was another pointer, this time directly to an `int`, and if you followed that address **then** you'd find an actual `int` number value.

```
int an_int = 3;
int* p = &an_int;
int** pp = &p;
```

This forms a chain ala...

```
int** pp = &p ------> int* p = &an_int ------> int an_int = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The first two are exactly the same.

int **i implies, i can hold the address of a pointer. That is, a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is insignificant in this case. `int * i` means the same as `int* i` and `int *i`. All are pointers to an integer. `int ** i` is different, this is a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

Comment: "Whitespace is insignificant in this case" - try telling that to the people who write C++ style guides ;-p I agree of course that it's insignificant to the meaning of the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are the same and are a pointer to an integer:

```
int* i;
int * i;
int *i;
```

This is a pointer to a pointer to an integer:

```
int **i;
```

Answer (score 0):

> int* i;

a pointer to an int. potentially used as a 1d array

> int * i;

also a pointer to an int

> int **i;

a pointer to a pointer to an int. potentially used as a 2d array

Answer (score 0):

`int *i;`, `int* i;` or `int * i;`

These are all identical because spaces do not make any difference.
It is used to hold the address of an integer. 
Usually used in a dynamic, one dimensional integer array.

Similarly,

`int **i;`, `int** i;` or `int ** i;`

Are all identical because spaces do not make any difference.
It is used to hold the address of a pointer to an integer. 
Usually used in dynamic, two dimensional integer array.